# Is there an easy way to refactor between coding practices to C#4 from C#1,C#2 and C#3

Tags: c#

I am going to admit that I am battling with changing face of C#  and unlearning what I learnt since starting out with C#1.

I started years ago writing greenfield C# 1.1 code and also currently work a lot with maintenance work on code that is written with previous versions of C#.
 Being exposed to the old ways of doing things is hard as I am battling to unlearn from code what I have written in the past and that I have to look at daily that was written in previous versions of C#. Having to maintain Java projects also doesn't help as it is similar to C#1. With time I could probably unlearn my bad practices but with project deadlines it is hard to do.

My lazy mind also is against me as its logic says if  I use OO and DRY principles and the code compiles my boss is happy and thinks all is good when I am just not simplifying my code with new ways of doing things.

I have started reading Jon Skeet's C# in depth 2ed as what it does it gives the code solutions to do a specific tasks  for each of C#1,C#2,C#3,C#4 each time showing the code examples how it simplifies code but I am finding it hard to remember and put into practice these new methods due to having to still deal with all this legacy code daily and still having to balance my jack of all trades dev jobs.

1. Is there an easy way to refactor between coding practices from C#1,C#2,C#3 to C#4 either on the fly or at compile time and give suggests either in English language or refactor the code for me.
2. Is there anywhere like a tool or a site I can see the changes for the same code between the C# versions excluding Jon Skeet's C# in depth book?

Comment: Resources for learning new language features and best practices would be a better topic for programmers.se.  This site is more geared toward helping with questions about specific code, not the code-writing process.

Comment: C# hasn't changed *that* much in the last 10 or so years, when you put the changes in relation to those in the .NET Framework Class Library. Are you certain that you are only talking about the language and its new features in later language versions?

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) would be a helpful tool to move your C# forward in many respects quickly.  It will point you to newer practices and make it quicker & less painful to employ them across existing code.

A couple forward-looking ReSharper refactorings that come to mind are:

- Static to Extension Method...
- Property to Auto Property...

Also, ReSharper will, for example, encourage you to use `var` for implicit declarations where possible.

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/coderush-features.xml) can do much the same, but I have not used it as recently.

To see the difference between where such tools' refactorings put you and where you started, diffing against prior revisions of your files in source control comes to mind.

For changes to the .NET BCL alongside C# as @stakx points out, consider digging into build warnings regarding deprecated code built against newer versions of .NET.  Once you learn (as just one example) to replace uses of `System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader` with `System.Xml.XmlReader`, making the change in other places flagged for the former deprecated type will become quick.

[What's Obsolete in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee461502%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN characterizes the most recent BCL deprecations since .NET 1.1 and how to update affected code.